# Getting the maximum and minimum size of disjoint subsets

Tags: disjoint-sets, disjoint-union

I am writing code to perform Union-Find on a graph,

The first line of input is:
n m [n is number of nodes, and m is number of edges]

Then m lines follow, indicating which two nodes are connected

When I encounter each edge, I perform an union operation, to connect the nodes. After performing the union, I also want to know the size of the largest subset and the smallest subset

This is my code so far,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[100001];
int size[100001];

void initialize(int n){
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
        size[i] = 1;
    }
}

int root(int a){
    while(arr[a] != a){
        //Path compression
        arr[a] = arr[arr[a]];
        a = arr[a];
    }
    return a;
}

void weighted_union(int a, int b){
    int root_a = root(a);
    int root_b = root(b);
    //Perform union, if the two elements are not already in the same subset
    if(root(a) != root(b)){
        if(size[root_a] < size[root_b]){
            arr[root_a] = root_b;
            size[root_b] += size[root_a];
        }
        else{
            arr[root_b] = root_a;
            size[root_a] += size[root_b];
        }
    }
}

void print_result(int n){
    int max_size = 1;
    int min_size = 100000;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        //If it's a root node, then check the size
        if(arr[i] == i){
            if(size[i] > max_size){
                max_size = size[i];
            }
            if(size[i] < min_size){
                min_size = size[i];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<max_size - min_size<<endl;
}

int main() {
    //For fast IO
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int n,m,a,b;
    cin>>n>>m;
    initialize(n);
    for(int edge=0; edge<m; edge++){
        cin>>a>>b;
        weighted_union(a,b);
        print_result(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using brute-force to get the minimum sized subset and maximum sized subset. This code is getting timed out in Sphere Online Judge.

What would be a more efficient way of getting the minimum sized subset and maximum sized subset.

The SPOJ question link is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/LOSTNSURVIVED/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of using a disjoint set is right. You are getting a TLE however because your complexity is `O(N*Q)` which won't pass on seeing the constraints. You can optimise your algorithm to get a `O(Q*log(N))`. 
You basically need the max and min size at any point of time. These will change only during an update. You can keep track of the max size in `O(1)` by simply checking after each update whether the newly formed group's size > max. For min, you can use a BST to store the values of nodes ordered by sizes . Better use C++ STL `set` . For every union you do, delete the two nodes( I mean the parents corresponding to the query nodes) from the tree and insert the new parent with size. As insertion and deletion takes `O(logN)` time, your complexity becomes `O(QlogN+NlogN)` [`O(NlogN)` to build the tree]